# How can I convert a mathematically defined shape into a 3D printable G-code file?

Tags: 3d-models, cad, freecad

Suppose I have the X, Y, and Z coordinates (either in a list or a function z = f(x,y)) that defines a shape as the one provided and I want to 3D print it with a solid bottom, is there an easy way to do this? If not, how can a functionally well-defined shape be put into a 3D modeling software like FreeCAD?

[image: 3D graph]

Answer (score 2):

For stuff like this, OpenSCAD is your friend. There are several different approaches you could take:

1. Generate an image file with grayscale color representing the height of the function on an XY grid, and use the [`surface`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Other_Language_Features#Surface) feature to import it as a heightmap.
2. Write the function as a mathematical expression in OpenSCAD language, and write a module to generate a [`polyhedron`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Primitive_Solids#polyhedron) by iterating over a sufficiently fine coordiante grid, sampling the function, and producing points and triangles.
3. Use a library someone else has already written for this purpose. I'm not aware of specific ones but pretty sure there are quite a few.

Comment: I try to use OpenSCAD when designing and it was my first thought when seeing the question. I have insufficient brain cells to contribute in the manner you did, however.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [Full Control Designer](https://fullcontrolgcode.com/) where you can define the path using Excel formulas and it will generate the GCode for you.

Answer (score 1):

You may generate a .stl file from your mathematical definition. You may write a program using a language of your choice to compute the .stl file.

Your image shows a lot of rectangles, each rectangle may be described as two triangles. The .stl file is a (very long) list of all that triangles. Each triangle is defined by the X, Y, and Z coordinates of the three corners.

```
solid name

facet normal ni nj nk
    outer loop
        vertex v1x v1y v1z
        vertex v2x v2y v2z
        vertex v3x v3y v3z
    endloop
endfacet

endsolid name
```

Each n or v is a floating-point number in sign-mantissa-"e"-sign-exponent format, e.g., "2.648000e-002". The triangle vertices should be sorted using the "right-hand rule", i.e. the vertices are listed in counter-clockwise order from outside.

The normal vector ni nj nk is set to zero.

The G-code file is generated from the .stl file using the slicing software for your 3D printer.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking exactly, but you can use this workflow:

1. SideFX Houdini: math function + STL file generation
   [image]
   [image]
2. (optional) FreeCAD: Import STL as mesh, do whatever you need to do in FreeCAD, export to STL
   [image]
3. a slicer: import the STL and slice it.
   [image]
   [image]